# Why is this jquery code not executing properly?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get an understanding on how to use JQuery with PHP and MySQL. I found this code online but it's not working for me. The code is supposed to be a simple login screen that uses JQuery to output messages to the user without redirecting the page. I have checked everything individually (database, files, filenames, etc) and everything works fine. If I remove:

```
"$("#myForm").submit( function() {
        return false;
});"
```

from the script, the login works but it redirects to the actual PHP page which is what I don't want. I want the output statements of the PHP file to pop up on the html page without redirecting. If I keep that part of the code there, nothing happens when I click the submit button (when the fields are populated). If I do not enter anything I get the message, "Please enter both username and password." as shown in the code so I know JQuery is working. But any time information is entered, nothing happens on submit. I believe the issue has something to do with the:

```
function(data) {
    $("div#ack").html(data);
});
```

parameter of the $.post function. I placed alerts throughout the script and the alert that was placed in that function was not executed. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Login Form: JQuery + PHP + AJAX</title></head>
<body>

     <form id="myForm" action="http://localhost/login.php" method="POST">
         username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
         password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
         <button id="submit">Login</button>
     </form>

     <div id="ack"></div>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src=my_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery code(my_script.js):

```
$("button#submit").click( function() {

    if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" )
        $("div#ack").html("Please enter both username and password.");
    else
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(data) {
            $("div#ack").html(data);
        });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP code(login.php):

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass');
    mysql_select_db('people');

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"] );
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"] );

    if( empty($username) || empty($password) )
        echo "Username and Password Mandatory - from PHP";
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE(username='$username' AND password='$password')";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        if($row[0] > 0)
            echo "Login Successful";
        else
            echo "Login Failed";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the login button will trigger both the javascript and login.php. In your case it will trigger only the javascript code because you block the form action with this code :

```
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;
});
```

There is no need for a form action right there because you don't need the php to be called directly. You will call it via AJAX and return the value inside javascript. You can check the $.post documentation right here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. So your onclick event function for the submit button is completely wrong.

A way of rewriting your code is :

1) Modify the onclick event.

```
$("button#submit").click( function() {

    if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" )
        $("div#ack").html("Please enter both username and password.");
    else
        $.post( "http://localhost/login.php",
        $("myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(data) {
            $("div#ack").html(data);
        });
});
```

2) Remove the form action like this :

```
<form id="myForm">
    username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br />
    password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
    <button id="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will give it a try now !

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `print_r($_POST)` to your `$_POST` variable. You will see that there is an empty array. Your problem is still in your script :

```
$.post( "http://localhost/login.php",
   $("myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(data) {
        $("div#ack").html(data);
});
```

As you can see you forgot a `#` when trying to access the DOM objects with type input inside the `myform` form. So to fix it, modify the script like this `$("myForm :input")` to `$("#myForm :input")`. You don't have to make any changes that I suggested before. I think it's a matter of not paying attention.

EDIT:

Oh and by the way you will never get this output into your HTML:

```
if( empty($username) || empty($password) )
    echo "Username and Password Mandatory - from PHP";
```

This happens because you send the AJAX request only when form fields are not empty. I suggest validating the forms inside the PHP only, because there is no need to validate them inside your javascript and inside your PHP. Here is how your code should look like:

```
$("button#submit").click( function() {
    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(data) {
        $("div#ack").html(data);
    });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please try include these scripts instead of the one of jquery in the header (please include them in the head tag):
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js

Also please check out the console log in Google Chrome to see if javascript is reporting any errors. Please post them here if you see  errors.

Comment: Try getting that code up and running with XAMPP. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with this code snippet a while ago and forgot about this post. So I thought I'd post the fix.

So apparently,

```
$("myForm :input").serializeArray()
```

was not grabbing the user input from the form like I had initially thought.

I fixed by grabbing the form values,

```
var uname = $("#username").val();
var passwd = $("#password").val();
```

And then passing them as parameters for the PHP script in the jQuery `.post` method. I also put the url instead of

```
$.post( $("#myForm").attr("action")
```

So the final result looked something like this,

```
$.post("someURL/myfile.php", {username: uname, password: passwd}, function(data) { 
    $("div#ack").html(data);
});
```

Everything worked fine afterwards.